# How do I get different outputs after choosing different radio buttons?

Tags: jquery, arrays, angular, typescript, output

I'm working on an Angular project. Radiobuttons should be used to create a fitness plan. I wrote an example for Stackblitz.to.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dfcnkc

I have several arrays and I want, depending on what I have chosen, that the perfect answer is given.

```
homeBreast = ['exercise1', 'exercise2', 'exercise3'];
homeBiceps = ['exercise1', 'exercise2', 'exercise3'];
homeTriceps = ['exercise1', 'exercise2', 'exercise3'];

breast = ['exercise1', 'exercise2', 'exercise3'];
biceps = ['exercise1', 'exercise2', 'exercise3'];
triceps = ['exercise1', 'exercise2', 'exercise3'];

homeTwice1 = [this.homeBiceps, this.homeTriceps]
homeTwice2 = [this.homeBreast]

twice1 = [this.biceps, this.triceps]
twice2 = [this.breast]


homeThrice1 = [this.homeBiceps]
homeThrice2 = [this.homeBreast]
homeThrice3 = [this.homeTriceps]

thrice1 = [this.biceps]
thrice2 = [this.breast]
thrice3 = [this.triceps]
```

For exmaple: if I use "How often you want to go train? Answer: 2" and "I want to train Answer: at home" this should be put out.

```
// for the first day in the week
homeTwice1 = [this.homeBiceps, this.homeTriceps]
// for the second day of the week
homeTwice2 = [this.homeBreast]
```

and when I check the Answer "3" and "in the gym" the output should be like

```
// for the first day in the week
thrice1 = [this.biceps]
// for the second day of the week
thrice2 = [this.breast]
// for the third day in the week
thrice3 = [this.triceps]
```

Does anyone have a tip or an idea how I could do it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider creating an array of arrays (jagged array) to aggregate the information.

For example, you can put the definition for home exercises into:

```js
home = [
  [
    [this.homeBiceps, this.homeTriceps],
    [this.homeBreast]
  ],
  [
    [this.homeBiceps],
    [this.homeBreast],
    [this.homeTriceps]
  ]
];
```

Then, `home[0]` will hold the exercising plan when the user selected two days, and `home[1]` will define the plan for three days.

Going further:

- `home[0][0]` will return the list of exercises for the first day out of two: `[this.homeBiceps, this.homeTriceps]`
- `home[0][1]` will return the list of exercises for the second and last day: `[this.homeBreast]`.

You can extend the array further by combining home and gym into a single array (named for instance `plans`), but in this case, it will be a good idea to use constants `HOME=0, GYM=1` to name the indices of the array.

Now it will be much easier to display the given plan when you read the user's options. Let's say, they selected frequency of *three times* and location *gym*, and you display `plans[location][frequency]`.

Comment: Nojekls it possible to return two list of arrays, like home[0][0] and home[0][1]?

Comment: When you return `home[0]`, you in fact return `[  [this.homeBiceps, this.homeTriceps], [this.homeBreast]  ]`, which is simply an array of `home[0][0]` and `home[0][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a single array and populate it with every single exercise. Each exercise should be an object that contains the name of the exercise and additional properties like training frequency and training location. Those additional properties will be used to filter down the array dynamically in response to the radio buttons selected.

```
[
  {
    name: "exampleExercise1",
    trainingFrequency: [2, 3, 4],
    trainingLocation: ["home"]
  },
  {
    name: "exampleExercise2",
    trainingFrequency: [3, 4],
    trainingLocation: ["home", "gym"]
  },
  ...
]
```

When the user selects 2 and "home", filter the exercises down based on the trainingFrequency and trainingLocation. "exampleExercise1" would be returned in the example above.